# PLSQL/Oracle Nested For Loop Insert taking Long time in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, query-optimization

Following  query is used in a procedure. 1st insert happening quickly but 2nd insert taking a long time . The First For Loop query returns 5000 records which is then looped through another query which returns 4000 records and then  performs 2nd insert based on a function return value  which is taking 15 mins to execute  . All the tables used are indexed  need help on  optimize the query ?

```
    declare
    LV_INCT_ROLE sy_employee_master.incentive_role%type;
    
    BEGIN
      
      FOR ASM1 IN (SELECT a.run_id,
                          a.emp_no         emp_no,
                          a.team_id        own_team_id,
                          b.team_id        team_team_id,
                          a.incentive_role
                     FROM SY_HLSIL_ASM_EMP              a,
                          SY_DSA_ASM_TEAMWISE_HIERARCHY b
                    WHERE a.emp_no = b.emp_no
                      AND a.run_id = b.run_id
                      AND b.run_id = 195) LOOP
      
 
        BEGIN
          INSERT   INTO SY_DSA_ASM_TEAMWISE
            (FROM_DATE,
             TO_DATE,
             RUN_ID,
             EMP_NO,
             INCENTIVE_ROLE,
             TEAM_ID,
             SUM_FOR_TEAMID)
            SELECT '01-jan-2021',
                   '31-jan-2021',
                   195,
                   ASM1.EMP_NO,
                   ASM1.INCENTIVE_ROLE,
                   ASM1.OWN_TEAM_ID,
                   ASM1.EMP_NO
              FROM DUAL
             WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'x'
                      FROM SY_DSA_TRANS_HLSIL H
                     WHERE H.RUN_ID = 195
                       AND NVL(H.CALC_INCT, 'Y') = 'Y'
                       AND NVL(H.HDFC_REACH_FLAG, 'N') = 'N' 
                       AND H.EMP_NO = ASM1.EMP_NO)
               AND NOT EXISTS
             (SELECT 'x'
                      FROM SY_DSA_ASM_TEAMWISE D
                     WHERE D.RUN_ID = 195
                       AND D.SUM_FOR_TEAMID = TO_CHAR(ASM1.EMP_NO));
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ins Tm err 2: ' || SQLERRM(-SQLCODE));
            raise_application_error(-20000,SQLERRM(-SQLCODE));
        END;
 
     dbms_output.put_line('1st insert done');

       FOR ASM IN (SELECT ASM1.EMP_NO         EMP_NO,
                           ASM1.INCENTIVE_ROLE INCENTIVE_ROLE,
                           ASM1.OWN_TEAM_ID,
                           --     P.TEAM_ID        TEAM_TEAM_ID,
                           P.REPORTEE_EMP_NO REPORTEE_EMP_NO
                      FROM SY_DSA_ASM_POPULATE_HIERARCHY P
                     WHERE p.FLAG = 'LOWER'
                       AND P.EMP_NO = ASM1.EMP_NO
                       AND P.RUN_ID = ASM1.RUN_ID
                       AND P.RUN_ID = 195) LOOP
        
     
        
          LV_INCT_ROLE := UPPER(package.function
                                          (ASM.REPORTEE_EMP_NO,'31-jan-2021');  
                                                          
                                                                            
                                                                        
        
 IF INSTR(package.fucntion('INCT_RL_TL_ABOV'),UPPER(TRIM(LV_INCT_ROLE))) > 0
                    THEN
            BEGIN
                         INSERT INTO SY_DSA_ASM_TEAMWISE
                (FROM_DATE,
                 TO_DATE,
                 RUN_ID,
                 EMP_NO,
                 INCENTIVE_ROLE,
                 TEAM_ID,
                 SUM_FOR_TEAMID)
                SELECT  '01-jan-2021',
                       '31-jan-2021',
                       195,
                       ASM.EMP_NO,
                       ASM.INCENTIVE_ROLE,
                       ASM.OWN_TEAM_ID,
                       ASM.REPORTEE_EMP_NO
                  FROM DUAL
                 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'x'
                          FROM SY_DSA_TRANS_HLSIL H
                         WHERE H.RUN_ID = 195
                           AND NVL(H.CALC_INCT, 'Y') = 'Y'
                           AND NVL(H.HDFC_REACH_FLAG, 'N') = 'N'  
                           AND H.EMP_NO = ASM.REPORTEE_EMP_NO)
                   AND NOT EXISTS
                 (SELECT 'x'
                          FROM SY_DSA_ASM_TEAMWISE D
                         WHERE D.RUN_ID = 195
                           AND D.EMP_NO = ASM.EMP_NO
                           AND D.SUM_FOR_TEAMID =
                               TO_CHAR(ASM.REPORTEE_EMP_NO));
            EXCEPTION
              WHEN OTHERS THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ins Tm err 3: ' || SQLERRM(-SQLCODE));
            END;
          END IF;
        END LOOP; 
      END LOOP;
     dbms_output.put_line('2nd insert done');
    
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ins Tm err 4: ' || SQLERRM(-SQLCODE));
    END;
```

Comment: Please share full execution plan for the slow insert statement

Comment: That code is very ugly. Put some CURSOR and work with less blocks. You are engining a lot of lines of code, but that is not a good practice, the way is to do more with less.